# Python requests Invalid URL, verify failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

With verify = False in the url I get this error: requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?

When I leave it out of the url I get this error:
SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate

In both cases verify = False is in response = requests.request.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

src = input('Source > ')
dst = input('Destination > ')
svc = input('port > ')

url = requests.get('https://192.168.1.1/securetrack/api/topology/path', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'p@ss'))

querystring = {"src":src,"dst":dst,"service": svc}

headers = {
    'Accept': "application/json",
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring, verify=False)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: can you include the full traceback?

Comment: Your `url` is  not a URL but a response object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `url` variable contains a requests object, which you then try to pass as a url string in `requests.request`. Try this:

```
import requests
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

src = input('Source > ')
dst = input('Destination > ')
svc = input('port > ')
url = 'https://192.168.1.1/securetrack/api/topology/path'

querystring = {"src":src,"dst":dst,"service": svc}

headers = {
    'Accept': "application/json",
    }

response = requests.request(method="GET", url=url, headers=headers, params=querystring, verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'p@ss'))
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

src = input('Source > ')
dst = input('Destination > ')
svc = input('port > ')

url = 'https://192.168.1.1/securetrack/api/topology/path'

querystring = {"src":src,"dst":dst,"service": svc}

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring, verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'p@ss'))

print(response.text)
```